# Method of generic Java class that only works for Integer

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I have a generic class like the Java Linked List with a method sum() which should only be accessible if the list is of type Integer.
The constructor and sum() method look like this:

```
public class JList<T> {
    public JNode<T> sentinel;

    public JList() {
        this.sentinel = new JNode<T>();
    }

    // Sum of every entry
    public int sum() {
        JNode<Integer> n = (JNode<Integer>) this.sentinel.next;
        int sum = 0;

        while (n != null) {
            sum += n.element;
            n = n.next;
        }
        return sum;
    }

...
```

Before executing the method I dont want to ask whether the sentinel is instace of Integer. I was wondering if there was a way to not show sum() at all if the list is of type String

I tried changing JList to an abstract class and implementing a seperate class for Integers like this:

```
public abstract class JList<T> {
    public JNode<T> sentinel;

    public JList() {
        this.sentinel = new JNode<T>();
    }
    
    public abstract int sum();
```

and

```
public class JListInteger extends JList<Integer> {

    public int sum() {
        JNode<Integer> n = (JNode<Integer>) this.sentinel.next;
        int sum = 0;

        while (n != null) {
            sum += n.element;
            n = n.next;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

But when trying to create a list

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JList<String> l1 = new JList<>();
    }
}
```

it says "Cannot instantiate the type JList"

Comment: How about a static method `public static int sum(JList<Integer> list)`?

Comment: You get the _"Cannot instantiate the type JList"_ because `JList` is abstract. You cannot create instances of an abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inheritance attempt is correct. Just don't make the base class `abstract`, so that you can instantiate it.

```
public class JList<T> {
    public JNode<T> sentinel;

    public JList() {
        this.sentinel = new JNode<T>();
    }
}
```

Note that the `sum` method should only be defined for the `JListInteger` sub class, since the base class doesn't necessarily support `sum` operation.

Comment: But then I would have to create a new Integer list with JListInteger right? I would like to still do that via JList<Integer>

Comment: @Jasper Yes, you'll have to create an instance of `JListInteger`.

Comment: @Jasper That would always have been the case, even with your original attempt.

Comment: Is there no possible way around that?

Comment: @Jasper you can take the static method approach khelwood suggested in a comment, but if you want an instance method, I don't think there is.